# LINQ to SQL Union and then Join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have tables similar like Employee, Manager, Branch, Division, Employee_history

And let us say two tables Employee and Manager share certain columns like employee_id, name, branch_id

Branch table has branch_id

Division table has division_id

Employee_history has emp_hist_id.
All of these tables are one-many relationships

The SQL I want to convert to LINQ is

```
select b.branch_id, e.employee_id 
from division d
join branch b on d.division_id = b.division_id
join 
      (   select employee_id, branch_id
          from EMPLOYEE 
          UNION 
          select employee_id, branch_id
          from MANAGER
       ) e
on e.branch_id = b.branch_id
join EMPLOYEE_HISTORY eh on eh.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

How do i do a UNION and then a join. I have put a simplified version of SQL than what I have. In my actual SQL, there are two or three joins before Branch table and one join after the union

And my LINQ looks like (similar to actual code)

```
  from division in divisions
  join brnch in Branch on division.division_id equals brnch.division_id
  join empl in (
        from emplyee in Employee select new { EmployeeId = emplyee.employee_id},  BrnachId = branch_id).Union(
        from mngr in Manager select new { EmployeeId = mngr.employee_id, BrnachId = branch_id)
   on brnch.branch_id equals empl.BranchId
  join emplhistory in EMPLOYEE_HISTORY on empl.EmployeeId equals emplhistory.employee_id
  where division.division_type_id = 10
  select new
  {
     //...
  }
```

I am getting the error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

In the line that starts with 'join empl in ('

Comment: i tried.. but I could not get it compiled itself.. so I am not sure whatever I have tried will be helpful

Comment: All of these operations are supported, with 1-1 mappings, in LINQ.  Have you *tried* to implement this using LINQ?  It will look *very* similar.

Comment: @ajp You should include what you tried, mostly to demonstrate that you have put effort into solving the problem rather than just having us do your work for you.  Also include what errors you're getting.

Comment: Your sample SQL doesn't work - your subquery does not have a `branch_id` column to join on.

Comment: SQL seems ineffecient, couldn't you use `Select branch_id, employee_id from employee UNION select breach_id, employee_id from manager`?

Answer (score 0):

In `LINQ` the order of the statements is a little bit reversed, as opposed to `SQL`. And **when making a `.Join()` make sure the property names and types(!) are equal**. You can't simply join an `int` on an `int?`, you have to cast the `int` to be `int?` also.

In the example below, I suppose the `Branch_ID` on `Employee` and `Manager` are nullable (`int?`).

```
DataContext.GetTable<Employee>()
    .Select(e => new { e.ID, e.Name, e.Branch_ID })
    .Union(DataContext.GetTable<Manager>()
            .Select(m => new { m.ID, m.Name, m.Branch_ID }))
    .Join(DataContext.GetTable<Branch>(), 
            u => new { Branch_ID = u.Branch_ID },
            b => new { Branch_ID = (int?)b.ID },
            (u, b) => new { u.ID, u.Name, u.Branch_ID, b.Branch_Name })
    .Select(j => new { j.ID, j.Name, j.Branch_ID, j.Branch_Name });
```

---

And to finish it, I applied this to the actual code:

```
divisions
    .Where(d => d.division_type_id == 10)
    .Join(branches, 
          d => (int?)d.division_id, 
          b => b.division_id, 
          (d, b) => new { b.branch_id }) // j1
    .Join(employees
            .Select(e => new { e.employee_id, e.branch_id })
            .Union(managers
                     .Select(m => new { m.employee_id, m.branch_id })),
          j1 => (int?)j1.branch_id,
          em => em.branch_id,
          (j1, em) => new { em.employee_id, em.branch_id }) // j2
    .Join(employeeHistory,
          j2 => j2.employee_id,
          h => h.employee_id,
          (j2, h) => new { j2.employee_id, j2.branch_id, h.history_line }) // j3
```

Comment: Why join on an anonymous type with one property, `Branch_ID`, instead of just joining on the two ints?

Comment: As stated, I supposed the Branch_ID on the Employee and Manager to be nullable, as in a non-required Foreign Key. I thought this was something people new to LINQ are struggling with. At least I did... But when you suppose them to both be int, an anonymous type is unnecessary. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not you use an anonymous type, if one is nullable and one not then you need a cast.  You can add the cast without wrapping it in the anonymous type.

Comment: Mmm, learning something here! So an anonymous type is then only needed when joining on multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the `on` caluse of `Join` is slightly off.  In C# it is not:

```
on division.division_id = brnch.division_id
```

it needs to be:

```
on division.division_id equals brnch.division_id
```

This needs to be changed for all of the `on` clauses.